# How to find exact matches from two list & columns?

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup, countif

What formula would pull exact matches comparing column A & B from list 1 to list 2?

[image]

List 1 stays constant & list 2 floats with add-inns.

- if there's any additional info  a string would say ADD if true returns value*

This is my current formula => =IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,$D2,A:A,$E$2),$E$2,"ADD")
I attempted VLOOKUP formula, but column A has duplicates with different values in list.

Comment: Where is the formula you provide and what is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Return an Occurrence of a Value

- For the n-th occurrence of a value in a column, returns the associated (in the same row) value in a second (value) column of the n-th occurrence of the value in a third (lookup) column.
- Try the following array formula (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) in cell `E2` and copy down.

```vb
=IFERROR(INDEX(B$2:B$7,SMALL(IF(A$2:A$7=D2,ROW(A$2:A$7)-ROW(INDEX(A$2:A$7,1,1))+1),COUNTIF(D$2:D2,D2))),"")
```

**Formula Evaluations for Cell `E2`**

```
IFERROR                                 "b"
INDEX                                   "b"
B$2:B$7                                 {"b",1,2,5,10,20}
SMALL                                   1
IF                                      {1,2,3,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE}
A$2:A$7=D2                              {TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE}
A$2:A$7                                 {"a","a","a","b","b","c"}
D2                                      "a"
ROW(A$2:A$7)-ROW(INDEX(A$2:A$7;1;1))+1  {1,2,3,4,5,6}
ROW(A$2:A$7)-ROW(INDEX(A$2:A$7;1;1))    {0,1,2,3,4,5}
ROW(A$2:A$7)                            {2,3,4,5,6,7}
ROW(INDEX(A$2:A$7;1;1))+1               {3}
ROW(INDEX(A$2:A$7;1;1))                 {2}
INDEX(A$2:A$7;1;1)                      "a"
COUNTIF(D$2:D2;D2)                      1
```

Answer (score 0):

A potential solution would be the following:

On the first row, you can use a simple VLOOKUP as below:

[image: First row formular]

```
=VLOOKUP(D3;A3:B6;2;FALSE)
```

On the second row and so on, you can use the following formula (**attention on the details of the $ blocks you must apply**):

[image]

```
=IF(VLOOKUP($D4;$A:$B;2;FALSE)=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($D4;$D$2:$E3;2;FALSE);0);SUMIF($A:$A;$D4;$B:$B)-SUMIF($D$2:$D3;$D4;$E$2:$E3);VLOOKUP($D4;$A:$B;2;FALSE))
```